# namespaces cannot have embedded null characters

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

Application Details:
I am working on a web application in which I am using php as a server side language and mongodb for database. I am using a php mongodb library to connect with mongodb database.

Issue:
I can successfully create the DB connection from backend, using mongoDB library. But when I run the find query, I am getting following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'namespaces
>   cannot have embedded null characters' in
>   C:\wamp64\www\analytic_script\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Operation\Find.php
>   on line 180

Can anyone please let me know the possible solutions for this. Here is the find.php function where error is occuring.

```
public function execute(Server $server)
{
    $readPreference = isset($this->options['readPreference']) ? $this->options['readPreference'] : null;

    **// Error is occuring at this line**
    $cursor = $server->executeQuery($this->databaseName . '.' . $this->collectionName, $this->createQuery(), $readPreference);

    if (isset($this->options['typeMap'])) {
        $cursor->setTypeMap($this->options['typeMap']);
    }

    return $cursor;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like one of either `databaseName` or `collectionName` is empty, or contains `null` (`\0`) character as per the error message.

Comment: ok @KevinAdistambha, Thanks for your comments. While looking more into it, I found that the php mongodb extension was not compatible for the mongo package I am using. When I upgrade the extension version, It works perfectly. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade php7 extension mongodb 1.1.1 => mongodb 1.5.3

Comment: Some explanation as to why this helps would be useful.